# How to avoid the .idea directory when pulling from Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How can I avoid the creation of .idea directory on IntelliJ IDEA when pulling from Git?

Comment: Exclude the folder from Git?

Comment: Yes @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 3):

The folder should not be in the repo in the first place.

Since it is already there all you can do is to backup your existing `.idea` directory, let `git pull` overwrite it then remove it from the repository.

Add `.idea` to `.gitignore` (preferably to the global Git ignore file for your account) then run inside the working tree:

```
git rm --cached .idea
git commit
git push
```

Comment: That is not really correct. Most files in `.idea` **are** meant to be checked in, except you generate the files e. g. with Gradle. There are a couple of files like `workspace.xml` that are user-specific and should be ignored, but most other files are project configuration and should be the same for all team members and thus checked in or generated the same for all members.

Comment: @Vampire there are more files that are user-specific (`shelf/*`, `deployment.xml`, `vcs.xml` etc) but your remark is correct. However, the question asks how to not pull the `.idea` directory. Granular control over its content is a subject for a higher level of knowledge about Git and IntelliJ products.

Comment: Then probably the docs need an update: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directory-based-versioning-model.html

Comment: Here some additional ones are mentioned: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Comment: @Vampire AFAIK, most teams don't commit the .idea directory because of these hassles and because of the rate of change of these files. Usually developers are fine with idea regenerating these files.

Comment: @EngineerDollery which is total non-sense in **my** opinion, as those files are *meant*  to be checked in, because they define how the project is set up in the IDE. And those settings should not change often, but only if there are structural changes and then all members should get them. As I said, if you have some generation mechanism that generates the files like Gradle, or have a Gradle or Maven build that IDEA can properly import because it is simple enough, you are fine. But e. g. stuff like formatting options that should be the same for all members should also be checked in or generated.

Comment: @Vampire - your opinion seems to be based on projects where everyone has the same ide. Most real-world projects aren't like this. Your .idea folder goes out of date the second anyone with vim changes the project structure, and being out of date is far worse than not being there at all. If your project requires complex configuration that results in you adding .idea to the repo then it's likely that you've done something wrong.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Again just **my** opinion, but that is non-sense. The second someone with vim changes structure, everyone has to update their IDE configuration. The second the first one with IDEA got those changes and made the necessary adaptions, every other IDEA user just has to update and be done. But I will *not* continue this discussion in comments here, so this is my last comment to this thread. ;-)